# Do demons show up in auspex and how?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

If a vampire uses auspex on a demon (within a human host), does it show up on auspex?

And if so, beginning with which level of auspex and what are the indicators?

(I was sure there was a color assigned to demons, but didn't find it last I checked)

Comment: Hi, there! Can you tell us which edition of Vampire you're interested in?

Comment: based on that this was tagged WoD not CoD, it must be VtM not VtR.

Comment: @Trish Sure, but I wanted to be clear about whether it was V5, V20, Revised, or an earlier edition.

Comment: Indeed, however, V20 has no Fallen book, 5th edition so far only  has Vampire, Hunter and Werewolf (or about to have it)

Comment: V20 and revised mostlz but still as its not rules 5th shouldnt have changed the outlike too far_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Demons are called Fallen in the [table in question](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Aura#Supernatural_Auras). Their auras show up as:

> Plethora of rapid shifting colors that are difficult to discern